# Why in my nested set hierarchy is my HAVING clause not comparing int values properly?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, categories, nested-sets

I'm modeling a category hierarchy in postgres using the nested set model as explain [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). I am using a query to find the immediate subordinates of a node which is explained below in an excerpt from the article:

> Imagine you are showing a category of electronics products on a
> retailer web site. When a user  clicks on a category, you would want
> to show the products of that category, as well as list its  immediate
> sub-categories, but not the entire tree of categories beneath it. For
> this, we need to show the node and its immediate sub-nodes, but no
> further down the tree. For example, when  showing the PORTABLE
> ELECTRONICS category, we will want to show MP3 PLAYERS, CD PLAYERS,
> and 2  WAY RADIOS, but not FLASH.
>
> This can be easily accomplished by adding a HAVING clause to our
> previous query:
>
> ```
> SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - (sub_tree.depth + 1)) AS depth
> FROM nested_category AS node,
>         nested_category AS parent,
>         nested_category AS sub_parent,
>         (
>                 SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
>                 FROM nested_category AS node,
>                         nested_category AS parent
>                 WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
>                         AND node.name = 'PORTABLE ELECTRONICS'
>                 GROUP BY node.name
>                 ORDER BY node.lft
>         )AS sub_tree WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
>         AND node.lft BETWEEN sub_parent.lft AND sub_parent.rgt
>         AND sub_parent.name = sub_tree.name GROUP BY node.name HAVING depth <= 1 ORDER BY node.lft;
> ```

My schema differs slightly from the articles schema in the following ways:

- I'm using postgres. The article is using MySql.
- My category definitions live in a separate table
- My hierarchy table is called `category_tree`. The article calls theirs `nested_category`

Here is my category table definition:

```
(
    category_id uuid NOT NULL,
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    description text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_by text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    image_url text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    is_main boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    CONSTRAINT category_category_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (category_id),
    CONSTRAINT category_category_name_key UNIQUE (name)
)
```

Here is my category tree table definition:

```
(
    category_tree_id uuid NOT NULL,
    category_id uuid NOT NULL,
    lft integer NOT NULL,
    rgt integer NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_by text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT category_tree_pkey PRIMARY KEY (category_tree_id)
)
```

I have translated the query in the article to fit the schema in my db to the following:

```
SELECT node.category_tree_id,
       node.category_id,
       cat.name,
       node.lft,
       node.rgt,
       ( Count(parent.category_tree_id) - ( sub_tree.depth + 1 ) ) AS depth,
       node.created_at,
       node.updated_at,
       node.updated_by
FROM   category_tree AS node
       JOIN category cat
         ON cat.category_id = node.category_id,
       category_tree AS parent,
       category_tree AS sub_parent,
       (SELECT node.category_tree_id,
               ( Count(parent.category_tree_id) - 1 ) AS depth
        FROM   category_tree AS node,
               category_tree AS parent
        WHERE  node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
               AND node.category_tree_id = 'f47f6269-9605-459e-a319-2b0177f9f4d0' //lookup by category tree id
        GROUP  BY node.category_tree_id
        ORDER  BY node.lft) AS sub_tree
WHERE  ( node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt )
       AND ( node.lft BETWEEN sub_parent.lft AND sub_parent.rgt )
       AND ( sub_parent.category_tree_id = sub_tree.category_tree_id )
GROUP  BY node.category_tree_id,
          depth,
          cat.name
HAVING depth <= 1
ORDER  BY node.lft
```

This query does not produce any results and the issue seems to be coming from the `HAVING depth ...` clause. I have two rows in my `category_tree` table who's `depth` value are `0` and `1`, respectively as shown below:

```
"f47f6269-9605-459e-a319-2b0177f9f4d0", "d06a143b-523e-4136-8a17-1049abbf76f4", "Parent", 7, 10, 0
"14b939e9-6784-4905-ba24-f67768c57085", "21191930-a5b9-4868-883f-3798f29d70a3", "Child", 8, 9,  1
```

Oddly enough, if I change the clause `HAVING depth > 1` I actually get the two results I'm expecting, which is obviously wrong.

What's my issue here?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using nested sets, which are quite difficult, instead of [recursive queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)?

Comment: Recursive makes querying the tree inefficient as it gets large. I want flexibility in querying the tree

Comment: You might like the Closure Table alternative I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462) or [here](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/recursive-query-throwdown) or [here](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/sql-antipatterns/). I have queried trees of 500k nodes in milliseconds.

Comment: PostgreSql or Mysql?? Why don´t you tag correctly??

Comment: @nacho thought both were relevant since article is written for mysql and my question is for postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

You can't use a column alias on the same level where you defined it and having is only allowed in a query that uses aggregation. If you want to avoid repeating the expression, use a derived table. [-source](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/281438/why-does-an-alias-with-a-having-clause-not-exist-in-postgresql)

Full query:

```
SELECT node.category_tree_id,
       node.category_id,
       cat.name,
       node.lft,
       node.rgt,
       (Count(parent.category_tree_id) - ( sub_tree.depth + 1 )) AS depth,
       node.created_at,
       node.updated_at,
       node.updated_by
FROM   category_tree AS node
       JOIN category cat
         ON cat.category_id = node.category_id,
       category_tree AS parent,
       category_tree AS sub_parent,
       (SELECT node.category_tree_id,
               ( Count(parent.category_tree_id) - 1) AS depth
        FROM   category_tree AS node,
               category_tree AS parent
        WHERE  node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
               AND node.category_tree_id = 'f47f6269-9605-459e-a319-2b0177f9f4d0'
        GROUP  BY node.category_tree_id
        ORDER  BY node.lft) AS sub_tree
WHERE  (node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt)
       AND (node.lft BETWEEN sub_parent.lft AND sub_parent.rgt)
       AND (sub_parent.category_tree_id = sub_tree.category_tree_id)
GROUP  BY node.category_tree_id,
          depth,
          cat.name
HAVING (Count(parent.category_tree_id) - ( sub_tree.depth + 1 )) <= 1
ORDER  BY node.lft
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your query on MySQL and I find that your `depth` alias defined in the outer query is ambiguous with the subquery's column `subtree.depth`.

If I rename the outer query's alias something distinct e.g. `depth2`, and reference it in `HAVING depth2 <= 1` I get the two rows for "parent" and "child" as you would expect.

Comment: If I try that I am getting the error: "ERROR:  column "depth2" does not exist
LINE 29: HAVING depth2 <= 1". Hard to imagine that postgres would behave differently than mysql in this case.  I changed the alias on line 6 of my query to `AS depth2` and updated line 29 of my query to be `HAVING depth2 <= 1`. Did I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: That's exactly what I described. Change the alias name and then make reference to the changed name.

Comment: When I do that I'm getting the error I described in my previous comment.

Comment: Ah - this is indeed a postgres specific limitation. The reason I'm getting that error is because in postgres, where is evaluated before select, so you can't use alias declared in select in where clause.

Comment: You can't use an alias in the WHERE clause in MySQL either. What does that have to do with the HAVING clause?

Comment: I was wrong. Correction: You can't use a column alias on the same level where you defined it and having is only allowed in a query that uses aggregation. If you want to avoid repeating the expression, use a derived table. source: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/281438/why-does-an-alias-with-a-having-clause-not-exist-in-postgresql